# Images not uploading when htmlentities has 'UTF-8' set

Tags: php

I have a form that, among other things, accepts an image for upload and sticks it in the database. Previously I had a function filtering the POSTed data that was basically:

```
function processInput($stuff) {
    $formdata = $stuff;
    $formdata = htmlentities($formdata, ENT_QUOTES);
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($formdata)) . "'";
}
```

When, in an effort to fix some weird entities that weren't getting converted properly I changed the function to (all that has changed is I added that 'UTF-8' bit in htmlentities):

```
function processInput($stuff) {
        $formdata = $stuff;
        $formdata = htmlentities($formdata, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); //added UTF-8
        return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($formdata)) . "'";
    }
```

And now images will not upload.

What would be causing this? Simply removing the 'UTF-8' bit allows images to upload properly but then some of the MS Word entities that users put into the system show up as gibberish. What is going on?

**EDIT: Since I cannot do much to change the code on this beast I was able to slap a bandaid on by using htmlspecialchars() rather than htmlentities() and that seems to at least leave the image data untouched while converting things like quotes, angle brackets, etc.
 bobince's advice is excellent but in this case I cannot now spend the time needed to fix the messy legacy code in this project. Most stuff I deal with is object oriented and framework based but now I see first hand what people mean when they talk about "spaghetti code" in PHP.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use a different function to handle the image field as opposed to text fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function processInput($stuff) {
    $formdata = $stuff;
    $formdata = htmlentities($formdata, ENT_QUOTES);
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($formdata)) . "'";
}
```

This function represents a basic misunderstanding of string processing, one common to PHP programmers.

SQL-escaping, HTML-escaping and input validation are three separate functions, to be used at different stages of your script. It makes no sense to try to do them all in one go; it will only result in characters that are ‘special’ to any one of the processes getting mangled when used in the other parts of the script. You can try to tinker with this function to try to fix mangling in one part of the app, but you'll break something else.

Why are images being mangled? Well, it's not immediately clear via what path image data is going from a `$_FILES` temporary upload file to the database. If this function is involved at any point though, it's going to completely ruin the binary content of an image file. Backslashes removed and HTML-escaped... no image could survive that.

1. `mysql_real_escape_string` is for escaping some text for inclusion in a MySQL string literal. It should be used always-and-only when making an SQL string literal with inserted text, and *not* globally applied to input. Because some things that come in in the input aren't going immediately or solely to the database. For example, if you `echo` one of the input values to the HTML page, you'll find you get a bunch of unwanted backslashes in it when it contains characters like `'`. This is how you end up with pages full of runaway backslashes.

   (Even then, parameterised queries are generally preferable to manual string hacking and `mysql_real_escape_string`. They hide the details of string escaping from you so you don't get confused by them.)
2. `htmlentities` is for escaping text for inclusion in an HTML page. It should be used always-and-only in the output templating bit of your PHP. It is inappropriate to run it globally over all your input because not everything is going to end up in an HTML page or solely in an HTML page, and most probably it's going to go to the database first where you absolutely don't want a load of `&lt;` and `&amp;` rubbish making your text fail to search or substring reliably.

   (Even then, `htmlspecialchars` is generally preferable to `htmlentities` as it only encodes the characters that really need it. `htmlentities` will add needless escaping, and unless you tell it the right encoding it'll also totally mess up all your non-ASCII characters. `htmlentities` should almost never be used.)
3. As for `stripslashes`... well, you *sometimes* need to apply that to input, but only when the idiotic `magic_quotes_gpc` option is turned on. You certainly shouldn't apply it all the time, only when you detect `magic_quotes_gpc` is on. It is long deprecated and thankfully dying out, so it's probably just as good to bomb out with an error message if you detect it being turned on. Then you could chuck the whole `processInput` thing away.

To summarise:

- At start time, do **no** global input processing. You can do application-specific validation here if you want, like checking a phone number is just numbers, or removing control characters from text or something, but there should be no escaping happening here.
- When making an SQL query with a string literal in it, use SQL-escaping on the value as it goes into the string: `$query= "SELECT * FROM t WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";`. You can define a function with a shorter name to do the escaping to save some typing. Or, more readably, parameterisation.
- When making HTML output with strings from the input or the database or elsewhere, use HTML-escaping, eg.: `<p>Hello, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>!</p>`. Again, you can define a function with a short name to do `echo htmlspecialchars` to save on typing.

Comment: I agree that the code is messed up but, as it is part of a much larger and apparently very old codebase, I'm afraid to do much with it (and I do not have permission to do much work on it) and... in spite of everything it WAS working before the UTF-8 entity encoding flag was added. Why would it have worked prior to adding this? Also, how would you handle filtering MS Word entities? The only thing I can think of is to deal with each entity individually but I'm sure to miss one.

Comment: Heh, quite... it probably didn't! See if you can find where the `$_FILES['uploadname']['tmp_name']` content is being read and squirted into the database (is that really what's happening? or is it just storing a filename?). If the content going into the database is being sent through `processInput` then it should never have worked; try just sending it through only `mysql_real_escape_string` instead.

Comment: However, there is no such thing as an “MS Word entity”. Smart quotes are perfectly normal Unicode characters; if the application can't handle the smart quotes, it probably can't handle any other non-ASCII characters either. Though you can replace `‘` and `’` with `'` and `“` and `”` with `"`, that's not going to do anything for the 107,000 other characters that'll break.

Comment: OK, I followed the image through the form posting process (yes it is actually being saved into the database as a BLOB... personally I'd just save the path but anyway...) and what is happening is that the POST data is put into an object. The image is at $this->data['image'] and is being run through the following: $meh = "image= " . processInput(addslashes($this->data['image']) . ","; which is building a sql query (thus the image= and concatenation and what not).

Comment: `processInput(addslashes())`!! That's absolutely hilarious, adding the slashes and then immediately removing them again. Sigh. Replace this nonsense with `"image='".mysql_real_escape_string()."'"`. Now you'd be putting the image data directly inside the database. The potential problem will follow if, when the images are fetched back out of the database again, some idiot is calling `html_entity_decode()` on the mangled data put there from `processInput` to try to get the original bytes back!

Comment: OK, when I saw that my reaction was similar and I immediately changed it to mysql_real_escape_string. But output was still not working. I fiddled with it, couldn't understand why in the world it wouldn't work, came back here and saw your latest comment... you won't believe it (well, actually you probably will) but they did indeed use html_entity_decode() just as you speculated. Wow.

Comment: Oh! Just... revolting. :-) And if you fix it, the existing contents of the database would need to be changed to match, right? So you have to decide: fix the problem and de-entity-ify all the data in the database to match, or go for the quick fix of Dav's comment: adding a different processInput for the images to match existing behaviour, and using UTF-8-HTML-encoding for everything else, knowing the app is probably still all full of holes inside! Which you choose... well, are you going to be charged with looking after this app in the future? :-)

Comment: I chose quick fix. They allowed 2 hours total for this and after seeing just how deep and messy this went... ugh, no point in wasting my time as I have many other things to deal with. I got it working for them and that's all they care about (I did explain what "should" be done here but they weren't too enthusiastic). I will occasionally maintain this but only in a "put out fires" capacity and there will be no resources devoted to reworking it in the foreseeable future.